# Maps API: Finding the longest common path in two given paths

Tags: algorithm, api, google-maps, bing-maps

Google maps and Bing maps have methods that can give the directions from point A to point B on a map. This highlights a path from A to B on the map - call this P1
Suppose, P2 is another path from C to D (some other points), how can we find the longest common length of path between paths P1 and P2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have plenty of ways to do what you want.
Curiously, I tried to do it using JavaScript only and to do so, I used JSTS library that would compute the intersection between two routes (in my case, the geometry were retrieved from Bing, but I did not include the request in this example as it's not helpful).

**Use case:**

So, you want to have the common path between two paths (or the part of a route where you can use car-sharing or where you can run with your friend for example), if this is correct, then this example will help you.

**Libraries:**

First, the following library is need: JSTS, you can get it through Github dedicated repository: https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts

On other interesting library is Turf available here: https://github.com/Turfjs/

**Implementation with JSTS and leaflet:**

Here is the piece of JavaScript that will be interesting in this case:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var routeCoordinatesA = [[50.619512, 3.061242]....TRUNCATED FOR READIBILITY** ];
var routeCoordinatesB = [[50.619512, 3.061242]....TRUNCATED FOR READIBILITY** ];

$(function () {
    var map = L.map('map').setView([47.5, 2.75], 5);

    // Add base tile layer - sample from Leaflet website
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/transport/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    var polylineA = L.polyline(routeCoordinatesA, { color: '#4b98dc' }).addTo(map);
    var polylineB = L.polyline(routeCoordinatesB, { color: '#de6262' }).addTo(map);

    var geometryFactory = new jsts.geom.GeometryFactory();

    // Coordinates adapted to match for jsts
    var coordsA = [];
    $.each(routeCoordinatesA, function (idx, current) { coordsA.push([current[1], current[0]]); });

    var coordsB = [];
    $.each(routeCoordinatesB, function (idx, current) { coordsB.push([current[1], current[0]]); });

    // Element A
    var coordinatesA = bindCoord2JTS(coordsA);
    var shellA = geometryFactory.createLinearRing(coordinatesA);
    var jstsPolygonA = geometryFactory.createPolygon(shellA);

    // Element b
    var coordinatesB = bindCoord2JTS(coordsB);
    var shellB = geometryFactory.createLinearRing(coordinatesB);
    var jstsPolygonB = geometryFactory.createPolygon(shellB);

    // Interection
    var bufferTolerance = (2 / 1000);   // Small buffer to avoid different node no detection
    var intersection = shellA.buffer(bufferTolerance).intersection(shellB);  

    var intersectionPoints = [];
    $.each(intersection.getCoordinates(), function (idx, current) {
        intersectionPoints.push([current.x, current.y]);
    });
    intersectionPoints.pop();
    var intersectionLine = L.polyline(intersectionPoints, { color: '#4fc281', weight: 8 }).addTo(map);

    map.fitBounds(routeCoordinatesA.concat(routeCoordinatesB));
});


var bindCoord2JTS = function (coords) {
    var coordinates = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
        coordinates.push(new jsts.geom.Coordinate(
            coords[i][1], coords[i][0]));
    }
    return coordinates;
};
```

You can grab all the working example among my Leaflet experiments available on Github as well: 
https://github.com/nicoboo/maps/tree/master

And here the page that implements what I was talking about: 
https://github.com/nicoboo/maps/blob/master/Boo.Maps.Web.LeafletExperiments/LeafletWithin/index.html

Here for the live demo: http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/nicoboo/maps/blob/master/Boo.Maps.Web.LeafletExperiments/LeafletWithin/index.html

**Considerations:**

Of course, this is really based on the client side and it might be usefull to have the information on the server-side, I would recommend to use a spatially enabled database so you can use the STBuffer() and STIntersection() methods directly on the column or results that you manipulate with the best performances.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to fully understand your request but both Bing maps ans Google maps API for the directions contains in their response a "distance" field which specifies the value of the directions.

Here are two links for both documentation:

[Bing Maps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701717.aspx) & [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#UnitSystems)

With that you could compare the distance value between the two path and find the longest.

Hope this help.

Comment: It was about the common path, so the path where the two route overlap each other. It's like a STIntersects() in spatial database.